# Как создать svg определенного размера

Tags: svg, viewport, viewbox

Начал изучать svg и немного запутался.
Комбинируя параметры `viewBox` и `viewport` можно масштабировать картинку в несколько раз, но если мне просто нужно создать svg фиксированного размера, например конкретно 50 пикселей, то что нужно сделать?
 Конечно сайты с иконками позволяют скачивать картинки разного размера, но хотелось бы самому уметь управлять размерами svg.
  Кто-нибудь может помочь разобраться?

Comment: если конкретно 50px то так и пишите viewBox в котором рисуете а вот width и height 50px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> если мне просто нужно создать svg фиксированного размера, например
>   конкретно 50 пикселей, то что нужно сделать?

1. Если будете создавать SVG в векторном редакторе, то нужно выбрать размер документа `50x50px` и рисовать внутри ограничивающей документ рамки. Что будет выходить за границы документа, будет обрезано.
2. В готовом SVG документе размеры изображения зависят от соотношения
   `viewport / viewBox = 1` при равенстве размеров изображение выводится в том же масштабе, как нарисовано.

Допустим вы скачали иконку `24px`

```html
<svg fill="#000000" height="24" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    <path d="M13.49 5.48c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm-3.6 13.9l1-4.4 2.1 2v6h2v-7.5l-2.1-2 .6-3c1.3 1.5 3.3 2.5 5.5 2.5v-2c-1.9 0-3.5-1-4.3-2.4l-1-1.6c-.4-.6-1-1-1.7-1-.3 0-.5.1-.8.1l-5.2 2.2v4.7h2v-3.4l1.8-.7-1.6 8.1-4.9-1-.4 2 7 1.4z"/>
</svg>
```

Вам нужно её увеличить в два раза `viewport / viewBox = 2` в этом случае необходимо увеличить `viewport` в два раза `width="48" height="48"`, при том же значении `viewBox = "0 0 24 24"`

```html
<svg fill="#000000" height="48" width="48" viewBox="0 0 24 24"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    <path d="M13.49 5.48c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm-3.6 13.9l1-4.4 2.1 2v6h2v-7.5l-2.1-2 .6-3c1.3 1.5 3.3 2.5 5.5 2.5v-2c-1.9 0-3.5-1-4.3-2.4l-1-1.6c-.4-.6-1-1-1.7-1-.3 0-.5.1-.8.1l-5.2 2.2v4.7h2v-3.4l1.8-.7-1.6 8.1-4.9-1-.4 2 7 1.4z"/>
</svg>
```

Более подробно о взаимодействии `viewport` и `viewBox` можно почитать [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?p=5)